# .htaccess RewriteRule Exception

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have the following rules in my .htaccess file. The problem is when I try to navigate to `site.com/news/wp-admin/`, it ends up in a redirect loop. From other questions/answers I've read, you can create an exception by using `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/news/wp\-admin/` but this does not resolve the issue. It still redirects. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

The below `.htaccess` is in my root.

```
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
RewriteEngine On
RewriteOptions inherit

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/news/wp\-admin/
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9\-]+)/?$ index.php?p=$1 [L,NC,QSA,B]
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9\-]+)/(option1|option2|option3)/?$ index.php?p=$1&type=$2 [L,NC,QSA,B]
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9\-]+)/(option1|option2|option3)/(.+)$ index.php?p=$1&type=$2&q=$3 [L,NC,QSA,B]
```

If I comment out `RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9\-]+)/?$ index.php?p=$1 [L,NC,QSA,B]` it works, but breaks the rest of my site.

This is the `.htaccess` in `/news/` where my WordPress is.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /news/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /news/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you have Apache 2 so that mean you have to do it that way:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?news/wp-admin/
```

In Apache 2 there is no leading `/` so we make it optional with `/?`
and there is no need to escape the `-` because it have no special meaning.

#### Edit

Additional removing `RewriteOptions inherit` will do it, because with this option you apply the same rules to subdirectory and this will cause your loop